# how to replace the monk when clicking?

Tags: javascript, html

how to replace the "fa-angle-left" icon with "fa-angle-down" when you click on it?

```html
<li class="has-sub">
  <a class="js-arrow" href="#"><i class="fas fa-user"></i>Users<i class="pull-right fas fa-angle-left"></i></a>
  <ul class="list-unstyled navbar__sub-list js-sub-list">
      <li><a href="<?=ADMIN;?>/user">User List</a></li>
      <li><a href="<?=ADMIN;?>/role">Roles</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Did you try using javascript? Add any code that you have.

Comment: i need help in JS

Answer (score 1):

You can check for one class using [`classList.contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/contains) and replace it, using [`classList.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/replace) based on the result of check .

(`classList` returns `DOMTokenList`)

```js
let pr = document.querySelector(".pull-right");

pr.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (pr.classList.contains("fa-angle-left")) {
    pr.classList.replace("fa-angle-left", "fa-angle-right");
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<ul>
  <li class="has-sub">
    <a class="js-arrow" href="#"><i class="fas fa-user"></i>Users<i class="pull-right fas fa-angle-left"></i></a>
    <ul class="list-unstyled navbar__sub-list js-sub-list">
      <li><a href="<?=ADMIN;?>/user">User List</a></li>
      <li><a href="<?=ADMIN;?>/role">Roles</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

If you want to toggle between left and right icon, you need to add else part to the if condition.

```js
let pr = document.querySelector(".pull-right");

pr.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (pr.classList.contains("fa-angle-left")) {
    pr.classList.replace("fa-angle-left", "fa-angle-right");
  } else {
    pr.classList.replace("fa-angle-right", "fa-angle-left");
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    />

    <ul>
      <li class="has-sub">
        <a class="js-arrow" href="#"><i class="fas fa-user"></i>Users<i class="pull-right fas fa-angle-left"></i></a>
        <ul class="list-unstyled navbar__sub-list js-sub-list">
          <li><a href="<?=ADMIN;?>/user">User List</a></li>
          <li><a href="<?=ADMIN;?>/role">Roles</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: @lev_ please check if this helps

Comment: @lev_ Glad it worked. Can you accept the answer as well?